# how to set node request not to follow redirect

Tags: node.js, node-request

I have read the [document](https://github.com/request/request):
**followRedirect**

```
- follow HTTP 3xx responses as redirects (default: true). This 
property can also be implemented as function which gets response object as a 
single argument and should return true if redirects should continue or false 
otherwise.
```

However when set the `followRedirect`

```
let options = {
     url: url,
     method: 'GET',
     headers: {
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36',
     },
     followRedirect: function (resp) {
         return false;
     },
};
```

the setting didn't work. `response.statusCode` should be 307 while I got 200.

Comment: `console.log(resp)` inside `followRedirect` and check the response received.

Comment: @Mukesh Sharma I added the `console.log(resp)`, but I found nothing was output.